# Python for loop not working inside user defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, gensim, cosine-similarity

I have gensim pretrained  model  and I was trying to find most similar words using `model.most_similar('word')` So lets say, I have word named as 'politics' so what I have done is

```
for i,q in model.most_similar('politics'):
    print (i)
```

This gives me output as a list of words. But, same thing when I put it inside function as :

```
def taxonomy(word):
    for i,q in model.most_similar(word):
        print (i)
```

when I used `taxonomy('politics')`, I get the error: `ValueError: cannot compute similarity with no input`. Is it something I did wrong?

## edit :

How I can append the `i` into blank array with same name as my word. i.e for present array name should be `politics`, I've done this, but not working

```
def taxonomy(word):
    word=[]
    for i,q in model.most_similar(word):
        word.append(i)
        return word
```

Comment: `taxonomy("politics")`?

Comment: Are you putting `politics` in quotes?

Comment: What is the value of the variable `word` when the error occurs? Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: @WStokvis no, i have written as i have mentioned.

Comment: @Mavrick there's your problem. `politics` is a variable (which you've likely not created. Thus the `no input`). You're looking for `"politics"` which is a string.

Comment: Your error was fixed in an edit btw.

Comment: By the way, the `for` loop is missing a colon `:` at the end. Your code raises a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @WStokvis Thanks,Please check my edited question.

Comment: @MatiasCicero I have corrected it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your latest edit, a few things need fixing.
Since you want to name your list the same as the input `word`, one solution is to use a global variable and create a list that way with `politics`. I've adjusted some of the spacing. For example, you were were returning the list inside the `for` loop instead of after. For information on global variables, you can find documentation [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables)

```
def taxonomy(word):
    g = globals()
    g[word] = []
    for i, q in model.most_similar(word):
        g[word].append(i)
    return g[word]
```

**Related example:** I used `enumerate` instead of `model.most_similar` for display purposes. Your function returns the list you created in the function as well as creates that listed globally so you can use elsewhere without calling the function again.

```
def taxonomy(word):
    g = globals()
    g[word] = []
    for i, q in enumerate(word):
        g[word].append(i)
    return g[word]

taxonomy('politics')
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

politics
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: len(politics) in `def tax(word):
    politics=[]
    for i,q in wiki_model.most_similar(word):
        for j,k in wiki_model.most_similar(i):
            for a,b in wiki_model.most_similar(j):
                    politics.append(a)
    return politics` and len(politics) in `def tax(word):
    g = globals()
    g[word] = []
    for i,q in wiki_model.most_similar(word):
        for j,k in wiki_model.most_similar(i):
            for a,b in wiki_model.most_similar(j):
                    g[word].append(a)
    return g[word] ` is different. Why so?

Comment: @Mavrick it's hard to tell what the issue is from the code in a comment. How drastic are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

you can either do this by like this-

k = [i for i, j in model.most_similar(word)]
print(k)